# Is there a way to record entire call stack (start to end) of methods called during execution of an app using Google Chrome or IntelliJ Idea debuggers?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm working on a rather complicated legacy app and the frontend part of it consists of few different applications, all written in either JavaScript or TypeScript with Angular 8+.

They are all designed to be executed at once and communicate with each other, but each of them inside own web browser, where web browsers being invoked on custom hardware with touch screen.

Every app is executed inside different web browser window, kind of like microservices, being used as a different part of a whole frontend interface menu screen.

They communicate through WebSockets, browser's Window postMessage .etc.

I want to ease myself debugging process, by just saving the entire call stack of a particular app, since the moment of invoking breakpoint and then resuming the app execution.

I know there are call stacks visible in both Google Chrome and IntelliJ Idea Ultimate's debuggers, but the contents of call stack windows (frames) sometimes changes during execution of an app, when doing step by step debugging checks, thus getting refreshed and be updates with new call stack frames.

What I'd like to achieve is the way, to just record/save the entire call stack log, right after I stumble upon debugging breakpoint and then resuming the app, thus allowing the app to just loosely continue executing without any locks.

I'm aware about possibility to just save whole stack of executions as a .json file using **Performance** tab inside Google Chrome's Developer Tools, but there is probably not an option to also save the parameters passed to each method during each call?

Do anyone of you know some better way to achieve my goal, maybe using another debugging tool for web development?

Cheers!